# Parsing a JSON config file with Aeson in Haskell

Tags: json, haskell

I am trying to parse JSON in Haskell, but I cannot find any useful documentation about this task. I was not able to make the following little program work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Word (Word16)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (pack, ByteString)
import Data.ByteString.Char8 ()

data AppConfig = AppConfig {
    database :: DatabaseConfig
} deriving (Show)

data DatabaseConfig = DatabaseConfig {
    host :: String,
    port :: Word,
    username :: String,
    password :: String,
    databaseName :: String
} deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON DatabaseConfig where
    parseJSON (Object obj) = DatabaseConfig
                <$> obj .: "host"
                <*> obj .: "port"
                <*> obj .: "username"
                <*> obj .: "password"
                <*> obj .: "databaseName"
    parseJSON obj = fail $ show obj

instance FromJSON AppConfig where
    parseJSON (Object obj) = AppConfig <$> obj .: "database"
    parseJSON obj = fail $ show obj

config = "{ \"database\": { \"host\": \"db\", \"port\": 1234, \"username\": \"ledger\",  \"password\": \"ledger\", \"database_name\": \"ledger\" } }\""

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let cfg = eitherDecode config
  case cfg of
    Left err -> fail $ "error: " ++ err
    Right ps -> putStrLn $ ps
```

The error message makes absolutely no sense at all:

> user error (error: Error in $: endOfInput)

So what is wrong with the code?

Comment: It's frowned upon to edit your question and completely change the error that you're asking about - people can end up writing answers that become outdated, as here (@Krom). Instead, delete your question or post a quick answer to your own question detailing how you fixed it, and then post a **new question** with the new error. Remember this is a Q/A site, not a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the type signature of `pack` from `Data.ByteString`

```
pack :: [Word8] -> ByteString
```

you see, that it doesn't take a `String` or some type implementing `IsString` typeclass, but a list of bytes. Let's fix that by using `Data.ByteString.Char8` instead of `Data.ByteString`.

Now, the following error ensues:

```
test.hs:36:12: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Either String’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO (Either [Char] String)
        Actual type: Either String (Either [Char] String)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: cfg <- (eitherDecode config)
      In the expression:
        do cfg <- (eitherDecode config)
           case cfg of
             Left err -> fail $ "error: " ++ err
             Right ps -> putStrLn $ ps
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do cfg <- (eitherDecode config)
                 case cfg of
                   Left err -> fail $ "error: " ++ err
                   Right ps -> putStrLn $ ps
   |
36 |   cfg <-  (eitherDecode config)
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's because `eitherDecode config` doesn't result in a value of type `IO a` for some type `a`, but in a value of type `Either String a`. So let's fix that.

Now the following error ensues:

```
 test.hs:36:27: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
                  with actual type ‘ByteString’
      NB: ‘ByteString’ is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
          ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
            is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal’
    • In the first argument of ‘eitherDecode’, namely ‘config’
      In the expression: (eitherDecode config)
      In an equation for ‘cfg’: cfg = (eitherDecode config)
   |
36 |   let cfg = (eitherDecode config)
   |                           ^^^^^^
```

Obviously we picked the wrong `ByteString` type. `ByteString` from `Data.ByteString.Char8` is strict, but aeson expects lazy bytestrings. So let's fix that by using `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8`.

Now it compiles and running the program gives the following error:

```
[nix-shell:~/tmp]$ ./test
test: user error (error: Error in $: endOfInput)
```

That's because your JSON in your string literal is wrong. It reads

```
"{ \"database\": { \"host\": \"db\", \"port\": 1234, \"username\": \"ledger\",  \"password\": \"ledger\", \"database_name\": \"ledger\" } }\""
```

It should read:

```
"{ \"database\": { \"host\": \"db\", \"port\": 1234, \"username\": \"ledger\",  \"password\": \"ledger\", \"database_name\": \"ledger\" } }"
```

recompiling and running test now results in the following error:

```
[nix-shell:~/tmp]$ ./test
test: user error (error: Error in $: expected String, encountered Object)
```

So obviously aeson thought it should decode a json string value, but encountered an object. If you look at the following lines

```
let cfg = (eitherDecode config)
case cfg of
   Left err -> fail $ "error: " ++ err
   Right ps -> putStrLn $ ps
```

you see, that `ps` gets typed as `String` because it is used as an argument to `putStrLn`, what explains the observed behaviour. If we just changed `putStrLn $ ps` to `putStrLn $ show ps` the compiler doesn't know at all, what type `ps` could be, so let's help him with a type annotation.

recompiling and running test now results in the following error:

```
[nix-shell:~/tmp]$ ./test
test: user error (error: Error in $.database: key "databaseName" not present)
```

So your program expects `databaseName` as key in the json object, not `database_name`. Fix the `FromJSON` instance to fix that.

Now it outputs:

```
[nix-shell:~/tmp]$ ./test
AppConfig {database = DatabaseConfig {host = "db", port = 1234, username = "ledger", password = "ledger", databaseName = "ledger"}}
```

The final program reads now:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Word (Word16)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (pack,ByteString)

data AppConfig = AppConfig {
    database :: DatabaseConfig
} deriving (Show)

data DatabaseConfig = DatabaseConfig {
    host :: String,
    port :: Word,
    username :: String,
    password :: String,
    databaseName :: String
} deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON DatabaseConfig where
    parseJSON (Object obj) = DatabaseConfig
                <$> obj .: "host"
                <*> obj .: "port"
                <*> obj .: "username"
                <*> obj .: "password"
                <*> obj .: "database_name"
    parseJSON obj = fail $ show obj

instance FromJSON AppConfig where
    parseJSON (Object obj) = AppConfig <$> obj .: "database"
    parseJSON obj = fail $ show obj

config = pack "{ \"database\": { \"host\": \"db\", \"port\": 1234, \"username\": \"ledger\",  \"password\": \"ledger\", \"database_name\": \"ledger\" } }"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let cfg = (eitherDecode config) :: Either String AppConfig
  case cfg of
    Left err -> fail $ "error: " ++ err
    Right ps -> putStrLn $ show ps
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an error in your input, rather than in the code. The `\"` at the end of your string looks suspicious, the contents of that string would look like:

```
{ "database": { "host": "db", ... } }"
```

Where the trailing `"` is causing a parse error.

Answer (score 0):

hnefati and Krom have provided an answer already (You had an extra \" character, you needed to add a type annotation in your decode function, and needed to match database_name with databaseName). For this particular example, if you are happy using a couple of language extensions, your code could be simplified as such:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module SO where

import Data.Aeson
import Data.ByteString.Char8 ()
import GHC.Generics          (Generic)

data AppConfig = AppConfig {
    database :: DatabaseConfig
} deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON)

data DatabaseConfig = DatabaseConfig {
    host         :: String,
    port         :: Word,
    username     :: String,
    password     :: String,
    databaseName :: String
} deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON)

config = "{ \"database\": { \"host\": \"db\", \"port\": 1234, \"username\": \"ledger\",  \"password\": \"ledger\", \"databaseName\": \"ledger\" } }"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let cfg = eitherDecode config
  case cfg of
    Left err -> fail $ "error: " ++ err
    Right ps -> putStrLn $ show $ (ps :: AppConfig)
```

Comment: You probably should provide a way to read the json key `database_name`. You can either change `DatabaseConfig` or use `genericParseJSON` and change the `fieldLabelModifier`. Maybe the op can't control the json he needs to read?

Comment: Indeed if the config file is outside of OP jurisdiction then this code would not work. It works only for the best-case scenario where OP provides the config file and is happy to rename database_name into databaseName.